# Word for referring to incomprehensible sounds produced by stuttering/stammering?

Tags: single-word-requests

At first I just decide to use **stutter** as a noun:

> David pulled himself away slowly, his face as pale as a ghost's. Some
>   words came out of his mouth. At first, they were just
>   incomprehensible **stutters**, but then they gradually began to take shape.
>   "Y-you're...you're not Sophia."

But then for some reason, it started sounding a little strange to me. Is there any other word to use in cases like this?

Comment: Just a minor stylistic note: You usually set off an ellipsis from surrounding text with spaces (and you can optionally put spaces within the ellipsis, ideally a typographer's thin space). Thus, “Y-you're ... you're not Sophia” or “Y-you're . . . you're not Sophia.” Although in this particular case I might prefer a dash: “Y-you're – you're not Sophia.”

Comment: Cool. Note that you can either use an en dash set off by spaces (like – this) or an em dash without spaces (like—this). Either form puts the right amount of distance between the words.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: An em dash seems somehow wrong to me here. An en dash I can accept (though I would prefer the ellipsis), but an em dash to me is too specific in setting off separate phrases, rather than being used for this kind of stammering speech. Do you know of any style guides that define punctuation for stammering? (I know em dashes are often used for interrupted speech, but that to me is an entirely different thing from stammering.)

Comment: @janoChen, to preserve tense agreement, it should be, “Some words _came_ out of his mouth”.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Thanks, I don't know what's with my brain today.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet En dashes are used to form ranges and compounds (like–this). Em dashes are used to indicate interruption of thought or speech (like—this). You can substitute spaced en dashes for em dashes (like – this) as a stylistic choice, in which case you should do it consistently throughout your document. See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) or Bringhurst for more information.

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not address this directly, and unfortunately, I do not have access to Bringhurst. Stuttering is not the same as interruption of thought or speech; it is delayed or repeated speech, rather than interrupted speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some of these:

- Jumble
- Ramble
- Drivel
- Rant
- Blather
- Incoherency
- Spatter
- Incongruence
- Discordance

Comment: Th- th- the- there's ***stammer***, too. From NOAD: _to speak with sudden involuntary pauses and a tendency to repeat the initial letters of words_

Answer (score 1):

[*Stutter*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stutter) is a fine word to describe the sounds made when stuttering or stammering. From the American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language (emphasis mine):

> *n.* The **act** or habit of stuttering.

From Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged:

> *n.* **2.** a stuttering **sound.**

Comment: Thanks, so it is properly being used in my example above?

Comment: Yes, it reads naturally to me, and it's pleasantly succinct.

Answer (score 1):

As possible alternatives to *stutter*.

> At first they were incomprehensible **mumbles**...
>
> At first they were incomprehensible **splutters / splutterings**...

- **splutter** *to utter hastily and confusedly or incoherently*
- **mumble** *to say or utter indistinctly, as with partly closed lips*

source: Dictionary.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions (by the way, have I seen you at Scribophile?)

Comment: No, you haven't. I don't even know what it is. :)

Comment: wrong person, sorry, ha. It's a community were you can post your work of fiction work and receive feedback.